# extract substring in string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following string:

expression_patterns_attributes_2_location_attributes_PTN_PATTERN

I need to extract only the number after 'expression_patterns_attributes_'

I did the following:

```
<%= string_a = "expression_patterns_attributes_2_location_attributes_PTN_PATTERN"
<% z_index1 = string_a.slice! "expression_patterns_attributes_" %>
<% z_index2 = string_a.slice! "_location_attributes_PTN_PATTERN"     %>
<%= string_a %> yields '2'
```

Is there a neater way of extracting the number from the string?

Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = 'expression_patterns_attributes_2_location_attributes_PTN_PATTERN'
s[/\d+/] # => "2"
```

Comment: Yep this is actually a lot more robust!

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that string_a is always well formed :

```
string_a.split("_")[3]
```